# I tried Php Laravel Migration, but got some errors, could anyone help me solve this?

Tags: php, migration, database-migration, laravel-migrations, laravel-10

Had an Error running Php laravel Migration.

I tried  php artisan make:migration rename_name_in_users --table=users, which was successful and edited the following;

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->renameColumn('name', 'username');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->renameColumn('username', 'name');
        });
    }
};
```

I got the following errors after using php artisan migrate;

```
2023_05_31_160724_rename_name_in_users ................................................................ 13ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'column `name` to `username`' at line 1 
(Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `users` rename column `name` to `username`)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:793
    789▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    790▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    791▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    792▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 793▕             throw new QueryException(
    794▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    795▕             );
    796▕         }
    797▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:572
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'column `name` to `username`' at line 1")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:572
      PDO::prepare("alter table `users` rename column `name` to `username`")
```

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you running? `RENAME COLUMN` was added in 10.5.2.

Comment: Version 10.4.27-MariaDB

Comment: There you have it. Upgrade and the problem should go away.

Comment: How do i upgrade?

Comment: Google told me: [Upgrading MariaDB on Windows](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-mariadb-on-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE t CHANGE COLUMN old_name new_name ((datatype specs))` is the old syntax for `RENAME COLUMN`.